# Como é possível declarar um objeto sem antes tê-lo instanciado?

Tags: android

Me deparei com uma dúvida na programação android, quando declaramos as Views na classe java, como no exemplo: (TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt)), essa View está sendo utilizada pela classe sem antes te-la sido instanciada?

Answer (score 3):

Julgo que você está a confundir declarar com inicializar/atribuir.

Na linha

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt);
```

está a ser feita a declaração, através de

```
TextView txt
```

e ao mesmo tempo a atribuição, através de

```
= (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt)
```

As views são instanciadas pela Activity durante o processo da sua criação.
O método `findViewById(R.id.txt)` encarrega-se de devolver a instância da view cujo id é `R.id.txt`, caso exista.

Comment: Entendi. A minha dúvida era essa, onde o método findViewById(int) encarrega-se de devolver uma instancia da view. Obrigado!